# How to get the form from a child component and emit to the parent

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have Parent component with a two childs.
I want to get the form from the childs and send to the parent everytime that is changed.

I have the parent form like this:

```
 profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
    address: new FormGroup({}),
  });
```

child 1 component:

```
 @Output() onFormEmit = new EventEmitter<any>();
  form = new FormGroup({
    child1Key1: new FormControl(''),
    child1Key2: new FormControl(''),
    child1Key3: new FormControl(''),
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onFormEmit.emit(this.form);
  }
```

child 2 component:

```
 @Output() onFormEmit = new EventEmitter<any>();
  form = new FormGroup({
    child2Key4: new FormControl(''),
    child2Key5: new FormControl(''),
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onFormEmit.emit(this.form);
  }
```

After the emit, I want the form to be like this:

```
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
    address: new FormGroup({
      child1Key1: new FormControl(''),
      child1Key2: new FormControl(''),
      child1Key3: new FormControl(''),
      child2Key4: new FormControl(''),
      child2Key5: new FormControl(''),
    }),
  });
```

And I also want to send the nested form to the child as a Input, so I need to keep the alive conversation between the forms.

this is what I have until now:
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ekvexk?file=src/app/parent/parent.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like 'nested forms' might be what you're looking for, where the parent `formGroup` is passed as an `input` to the child component - the controls in the child are added to that

There's three approaches described in the linked article, the first one is doing the above:

- https://www.dotnetsurfers.com/blog/2020/10/11/3-approaches-for-implementing-nested-forms-in-angular/

Answer (score 0):

So, why don't you emit child's `form.getRawValue()` after each change and when you get this data on the parent's event listener you iterate through object keys and values setting the result form fields ? In the end of the callback just send updated form to children again.